# Adding images into ListView

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to display some images into ListView but only the image path/url appear.

Here is my code to display images.

```
ListView1.View = View.SmallIcon
ImageList1.ImageSize = New Size(32, 32)
ListView1.SmallImageList = ImageList1

ListView1.Items.Clear()

ListView1.Items.Add("File path goes here")
```

This was my first time displaying images into ListView, so I don't really know on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have already set images in your `ImageList1`. If so,

```
ListView1.View = View.SmallIcon
'ImageList1.ImageSize = New Size(32, 32) 'Not necessary
ListView1.SmallImageList = ImageList1
ListView1.Items.Clear()
ListView1.Items.Add("File path goes here") 'Add 1 more parameter
```

The line 2 is not necessary.
And, 1 more parameter in `ListView1.Items.Add()` which is the image index.

[image]

EDITED:

```
ListView1.View = View.SmallIcon
ImageList1.ImageSize = New Size(32, 32)
ImageList1.Images.Clear()
ImageList1.Images.Add("key1", New Icon("C:\Test\test.ico"))
ListView1.SmallImageList = ImageList1
ListView1.Items.Clear()
ListView1.Items.Add("Text here", "key1")
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion. I really appreciate it. But if I remove the `ImageList1.ImageSize = New Size(32, 32)` my ListView will have a big gap between those items displayed. And I already tried adding the index like the one that you showed to me `0` but the result is still the same. My ListView is still displaying image url instead of image.

Comment: @Emerald, Do you mean you wrote something like `ListView1.Items.Add("C:\Test\test.ico")` in your code? And, you want to add icon and text dynamically to `ListView`?

Comment: Yes. Correct :)
How to do that?